# Where to get replacement black sticker for the front of a lens?

Tags: lens, repair, repair-parts

On a recent trip the filter threads came loose on my Nikon 18-200, and some of the screws that held it in place where caught in the black sticker that covers them.

I peeled off the sticker, and surprisingly it looks like there was no damage, so I just screwed it all back together.  I'm unsure whether I should try to reuse the sticker, or try to find a reasonable replacement; I can't really search for an answer since I have no idea what it's called.

Answer (score 1):

Your best to phone your lens manufacturer and try and explain the part you want to replace. They will have a far greater knowledge of the components that make up the lens. They will also be able to provide you with the parts sometimes at no cost.